# new command with cases / conditionals / 'if... then's

Tags: macros, conditionals

Suppose I want to define a command, say, `\tree` with, say, two arguments. I would like `\tree` to do different things depending on what my first argument is. For example,

if `#1` = a, then return `$\sqrt{#2}$`

if `#1` = b, then return "Hi"

Is it possible to realise the above pseudocode? If so, how can I?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can also use `\IfEqCase` from [the `xstring` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) which can easily be extended to add more cases:

[image]

### Notes:

- Besides being able to easily extend to more cases, this also has the benefit that it will produce a `\PackageError` if an unknown option is passed in.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\tree}[2]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {a}{$\sqrt{#2}$}%
        {b}{Hi}%
        % you can add more cases here as desired
    }[\PackageError{tree}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}]%
}%
\begin{document}
\tree{a}{4}

\tree{b}{4}

%\tree{c}{4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about if I need to use multiple conditions/variables for the same case, for example CASE1: if a=1 and/or b=2 : then do this and so on. Identifying multiple variables in the same case

Comment: @Silva: In general, you should be able to nest the cases, or perhaps make use of [Modified \IfStrEqCase with multiple matches per case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350815/4301). But, without seeing more details I can't give you an exact answer. If you are unable to locate the answer on this site, I'd suggest you ask a new question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. If this question is relevant you should link to it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529341/multiple-cases-for-xstring-package

Answer (score 18):

`ifthen` package then

```
  \newcommand\tree[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{$\sqrt{#2}$}{Hi}}
```

actually I mis read your condition so I suppose the full version is

```
 \newcommand\tree[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}%
                     {$\sqrt{#2}$}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{Hi}{zzz}}}
```

---

I think all the answers given so far (including mine above) are not *expandable* which means that you can't to the test in places like a `\write` or `\edef` see the `\typeout` below. Given your `\sqrt` example that probably doesn't matter, but the following is a version using *expandable* tests that is almost certainly the quickest version posted so far, although rather expensive in terms of command name use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{tree@a}#1{$\sqrt{#1}$}
\@namedef{tree@b}#1{h1}
\def\tree#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname tree@#1\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\@gobble\else
\csname tree@#1\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tree{a}{2}

\typeout{[[[\tree{b}{2}]]]}

\tree{b}{xyz}

\tree{x}{Uh!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, but what if `#1` is not equal to either `a` or `b`?...

Comment: @Mico you get zzz but you could make that a warning or error or nothing if desired

Answer (score 10):

The easiest implementation is with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tree}{ m m }
 {
  \seaton_tree:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \seaton_tree:nn #1 #2
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    { a } { $\sqrt{ #2 }$ }
    { b } { Hi }
    % other possible strings
   }
   {
    I~don't~know~what~to~do~with~`#1'
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tree{a}{2}

\tree{b}{xyz}

\tree{x}{Uh!}

\end{document}
```

The list of admissible strings can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution (+1). However, as I am not very well versed in Latex, some of the of parameters above are beyond me.

Comment: The `\prg_case_str:nnn` command is in the process of being renamed to `\str_case:nnn` as part of the LaTeX3 'small bang' (July 2012).

Comment: How to add some text without using `~`?

Comment: @Passe: Under `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `~` means a space.

Answer (score 7):

Another variation on the theme flowing through the answers is to use the `etoolbox`; same idea, just different syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\tree}[2]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{a}%
        {$\sqrt{#2}$}%
        {\ifstrequal{#1}{b}{Hi}{\PackageError{tree}{Undefined option to tree command}{}}}%
        }
\begin{document}
\tree{a}{4}

\tree{b}{4}

% this one throws an error
%\tree{c}{4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention what `a` and `b` are supposed to be, so I'll assume that they are character strings (possibly of unit length). The following construct, which makes use of the `\ifthenelse` macro of the `ifthen` package, should work for you:

```
\newcommand{\tree}[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{$\sqrt{#2}$}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{"Hi."}{}}}
```

Notice that you don't appear to specify what should be done if `#1` is not equal to either `a` or `b`. I've therefore set the outcome for that case to `{}`.