# new command with cases?

Tags: macros, conditionals

This has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61598/new-command-with-cases-conditionals-if-thens) for text outputs with the use of `\IfEqCase` from the [xstring package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/). But if I want to use the output as a value to set a parameter in a function, it fails.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{lettrine,xstring}

\newcommand*{\Lettrine}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=1, findent=\IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {P}{-0.8em}%
        {Q}{1em}%
    }[\PackageError{Lettrine}{Undefined option to Lettrine: #1}{}]%
    ]{\textit{#1}}{}%
}

\newcommand*{\LettrineSimply}[1]{\lettrine[lines=1, findent=-0.8em]{\textit{#1}}{}}

\begin{document} 
\LettrineSimply{P} erfectly working !
\Lettrine{P} ossibly it will work !
\end{document}
```

`\LettrineSimply` works, but I want to use different *findent* depending on the letter. In my attempt with the use of `\IfEqCase`, I have the following compilation error:

```
$ pdflatex MWE_lettrine_command.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE_lettrine_command.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 15 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
Loading lettrine.cfg
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/lettrine.d/lettrine.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(./MWE_lettrine_command.aux)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.17 \Lettrine{P}
                  ossibly it will work !
?
```

If I just *ENTER*:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.17 \Lettrine{P}
                  ossibly it will work !
```

Do I try to assign a string to the *findent* parameter? How can I solve that?

Otherwise, is it possible to define tables or associative maps inside commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your `\Lettrine` command certainly does some un-expandable things, we don't really need a fully expandable version of `\IfEqCase`.

> [image: lettrine]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{lettrine,xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Lettrine}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {P}{\def\@@temp{findent=-0.8em,}}%
        {Q}{\def\@@temp{findent=1em,}}%
    }[\PackageError{Lettrine}{Undefined option to Lettrine: #1}{}%
      \def\@@temp{}]%
    \expandafter\lettrine\expandafter[\@@temp lines=1]{\textit{#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\LettrineSimply}[1]
   {\lettrine[lines=1, findent=-0.8em]{\textit{#1}}{}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\LettrineSimply{P} erfectly working !
\Lettrine{P} ossibly it will work !
\Lettrine{Q} uite certainly it does work !
%\Lettrine{R} arely are errors encountered ! % generates error as expected
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about if I need to use multiple conditions/variables for the same case, for example CASE1: if a=1 and /orb=2 : then do this and so on.Identifying multiple variables in the same case

Answer (score 5):

You need the \ifeqcase to be defined as expandable macro. My solution uses only TeX primitives, no `xparse` package is needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\def\ifeqcase#1#2{\ifeqcaseA#1#2\end}
\def\ifeqcaseA#1#2#3#4{%
   \ifx#1#2#3\expandafter\ifeqcaseE\expandafter#4%
   \else\ifx#4\end
        \else \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
              \ifeqcaseA\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
                        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#4% 
   \fi \fi
}
\def\ifeqcaseE#1\end#2{}

\newcommand*{\Lettrine}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=1, findent=\ifeqcase{#1}{%
        {P}{-0.8em}% 
        {Q}{1em}%
    }{\PackageError{Lettrine}{Undefined option to Lettrine: #1}{}}%
    ]{\textit{#1}}{}%
}
\newcommand*{\LettrineSimply}[1]{\lettrine[lines=1, findent=-0.8em]{\textit{#1}}{}}

\begin{document}   
\LettrineSimply{P}erfectly working !
\Lettrine{P}ossibly it will work !
\Lettrine{Q}next test.
\end{document}
```

See that the different syntax is used for `\ifcaseeq`: the else part is in normal TeX braces.

I know that the question was LaTeX-type but we can compare the code which generates the same effect in plainTeX (using `\eqifcase` by @jfbu).

```
\input opmac

\def\eqifcase #1#2#3{\eqifcaseA #1#2#1{#3}\end}
\def\eqifcaseA #1#2#3{\ifx #1#2\eqifcaseE{#3}\fi \eqifcaseA #1}
\def\eqifcaseE #1\fi #2\end{\fi #1}

\def\letterfirst#1{\vskip.7\baselineskip\noindent{\it\thefontsize[24.7]#1}%
   \kern\eqifcase#1{P{-0.5em} Q{1em} R{.1em} S{.4em}}
   {0pt\opwarning{\string\letterfirs{#1} in unspaced}}%
}

\letterfirst Possibly it will work!
\letterfirst Qnext text.

\end
```

That is the beauty of TeX.

Comment: I cannot compile it: `$ pdflatex MWE_lettrine_command3.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
[cutted]
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Runaway argument?
lines=1, findent=-0.8em {\textit {P}}{}erfectly working ! \Lettrine {\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@lettrine was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.29 
     
? `

Comment: I actually need at least 15 cases.

Comment: @lalebarde: I missed one square backet in the second `\newcommand` after findent=-0.8em while I copied and pasted my code to stackexchange. Sorry. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @egreg: You are not right. my macro `\ifcaseeq` works with arbirtary number of parameters. You can try it...

Comment: @wipet I was using the first version. Now it works as advertised.

Comment: @egreg: My first version was the same as the second (i.e. accepts arbitrary parameters). Only the missing `]` in LaTeX part of the code was corrected.

Comment: The second solution is interresting but cannot be compared easily since you substitute also lettrine. I don't want to substitute lettrine by a hack because I want to be able to use the full capabilities of lettrine.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment on [wipet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179356/4686) but is a bit too long.

Here is another way to do an expandable `\ifeqcase`. The conditions are the same: we only compare single tokens. We use `\eqifcase` as name.

**Added note:** initial motivation in revisiting wipet's interesting `\ifeqcase` was to move the execution of the selected branch to *after*  the case-switch has been cleared. This being done it is just one step to make the `\eqifcase` into a macro which expands in only two steps, before executing the selected code. And another aspect (independent of the added "expand in only two steps") worth pointing out is that `\eqifcase` can be used as argument to macros which expand their argument via  \romannumeral-`0. I have added an illustration of this below.

> [image: eqifcase]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\eqifcase #1#2#3{\eqifcaseA #1#2#1{#3}\end }

\def\eqifcaseA #1#2#3{\ifx #1#2\eqifcaseDo{#3}\fi \eqifcaseA #1}

\def\eqifcaseDo #1\fi #2\end{\fi #1}

\def\test #1{%
    \eqifcase {#1}{{A}{aa}{B}{bb}{C}{cc}}{not found}}


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\test{A}

\test{B}

\test{C}

\test{D}
\end{document}
```

Illustration (using within macros expanding their arguments via f-expansion) and Extension (case-switch expands in only two steps; this aspect is not illustrated here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\eqifcase #1#2#3{\romannumeral0\eqifcaseA #1#2#1{#3}\end }

\def\eqifcaseA #1#2#3{\ifx #1#2\eqifcaseDo{#3}\fi \eqifcaseA #1}

\def\eqifcaseDo #1\fi #2\end{\fi \space #1}

\usepackage {xintfrac}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DOOPERATION}[1]{\eqifcase {#1}
    {+\xintAdd
     *\xintMul
     -\xintSub
     /\xintDiv
     T\xintTrunc}{\@gobbletwo}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Demonstrating the use within macros applying f-expansion to their arguments:

\xintIrr {\DOOPERATION -{113/355}{22/7}}

\xintIrr {\DOOPERATION *{1024/243}{243/1024}}

\xintIrr {\DOOPERATION /{\DOOPERATION *{1001}{999}}{\DOOPERATION *{77}{111}}}

\DOOPERATION {T}{18}{113/355}


\end{document}
```

> [image: ifcase extended]

Comment: OK, you have better code (only three lines) with the same result.

Comment: @wipet I have commented more on `\eqifcase` which was motivated by your interesting `\ifeqcase`

Answer (score 4):

You should use an expandable command as the value of `findent`, but `\IfEqCase` isn't. Here's a working version with `xparse`; I've added `\ignorespaces` so that it's immaterial if you leave a space after `\Lettrine{P}` or not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{lettrine,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lettrine}{m}
 {
  \lettrine[lines=1, findent=\lalebarde_case:n { #1 }]{\textit{#1}}{}
  \ignorespaces
}

\cs_new:Npn \lalebarde_case:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {P}{-0.8em}
    {Q}{1em}
   }
   {% none of the above
    \PackageError{Lettrine}{Undefined option to Lettrine: #1}{}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\LettrineSimply}[1]{\lettrine[lines=1, findent=-0.8em]{\textit{#1}}{}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document} 
\LettrineSimply{P} erfectly working!

\Lettrine{P}erfectly working!

\Lettrine{Q}uestion: will it work?
\end{document}
```

You should be able to add whatever letter you want; the order is almost unimportant; for greater efficiency, put the most frequent letters first.

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, but it does not compile for me: `! Undefined control sequence.
\lalebarde_case:n #1->\str_case:nnF 
                                    {#1}{{P}{-0.8em}{Q}{1em}}{\PackageError ...
l.30 \Lettrine{P}
                 erfectly working!` with pdflatex.

Comment: @lalebarde Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: I did a `texhash`, but it changes nothing.

Comment: Oh yes, I use texlive 2012 !

Comment: @lalebarde TeX Live 2014 is to be released shortly.

Comment: I have the same error with texlive 2013. Does your solution work only with texlive 2014? If yes, it is not an "acceptable" solution for me.

Comment: Did you fully update it after installing?

Comment: I updated the 2012 packages, some was already 2013, the I reinstalled texlive-latex. So, I am going to re-install every packages in one shot, to be sure every dependencies are right.

Comment: Still don't work after full reinstall. But I have learnt that Gentoo Linux does not use tlmgr.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code, from *jfbu* solution, mixed with what I have learnt from *wipet* and *egreg*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\def\eqifcase #1#2#3{\eqifcaseA #1#2#1{#3}\end }

\def\eqifcaseA #1#2#3{\ifx #1#2\eqifcaseDo{#3}\fi \eqifcaseA #1}

\def\eqifcaseDo #1\fi #2\end{\fi #1}

\def\Lettrine #1{\vspace{-4ex}\lettrine[lines=1,findent=%
    \eqifcase {#1}{{P}{-0.8em}{T}{-0.6em}}{-0.1em}%
    ]{\textit{#1}}{}}


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{section 1}
\Lettrine{P}owerfull macro !
\section{section 2}
\Lettrine{D}efault.
\section{section 3}
\Lettrine{T}remendous!
\section{section 4}
without lettrine to show that thanks to \textit{\\vspace\{-4ex\}} in the macro, we keep the same vertical space between the text baseline and the section title.
\end{document}
```

[image]
Big thanks to all the three of you, you are amazing !
EDIT: update thanks to remarks.

Comment: you can remove the `\expandafter` in your `\Lettrine`... `;-)`

Comment: compiling the code with `\vspace{-4ex}` makes the big letters overlap on my installation

Comment: @jfbu, yes, I have not changed the snapshot. Lettrines are intended to be used after sections. `\vspace{-4ex}` enables to keep the same space between the section title and the text, without consideration for the lettrine.

Comment: Updated. Of course, this *vspace* depends on the sections specifications. Here, 2ex would have been better.

Comment: you could perhaps use `\smash` to kill the vertical space occupied by the lettrine. No need for a `\vspace` then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have just tested it. `\smash` before `\lettrine` does not compile, and before `\textit` has no effect.

Comment: I had not tested. Using `\lettrine` with `lines=1` seems to use little of lettrine package. What about simply `\noindent\smash{\Huge\textit{T}}\kern-0.6em\relax remendous!` possibly made into a macro?

Comment: Continuation of this Lettrine story [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179542/incomplete-ifx) with a new problem when I try to add an optional argument.