# Configurable spacing after \dots

Tags: spacing, symbols, kerning, ellipsis

LaTeX adds some space after the ellipsis `\textellipsis`. This is enhanced by `ellipsis` package, which only adds space before certain characters (and also gives the option to configure “easily” the spacing between the dots and after):

[image]

However the spacing is “wrong”, for instance `…!`, `…:` or `…?` does not need the same amount (see `:` versus `?`). However, I'm lost in the `ellipsis.sty` and I don't understand half of it.

### How can we set a certain amount to each different character?

It would be great to have something like

```
\SetEllipsisSpacing
  {
    . = .1em,
    ? = .08em,
    ! = .09em,
    : = .1em,
  }
\SetEllipsisSpacing
  {
    { . } { .1em }
    { ? } { .08em }
    { ! } { .09em }
    { : } { .1em }
  }
```

instead of the current (and only) option `\def\ellipsispunctuation{,.:;!?}`.

Here is a minimal compilable example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Just here to be an example, I use a different font
\usepackage{ellipsis}

%\def\ellipsisgap{.1em}

%\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}
%  {{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\char133}}

\begin{document}
a…! …: …?
\end{document}
```

---

This comes because I discovered that the LY1 encoding has an ellipsis character, so I can define

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}
  {{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\char133}}
```

but it needs some adjusting.

[image]

Comment: The spacing *is* the same, but the question mark is farther right than with the colon or the exclamation mark.

Comment: I meant that the spacing is the same while I don't want it to be the same (the reason is that different glyphs might need different space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Just here to be an example, I use a different font
\usepackage{xparse,newunicodechar}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\newunicodechar{…}
 {
  {\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\char133}
  \manuel_lookup:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\SetEllipsisSpacing { m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { manuel/ellipsis } { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_manuel_list_tl

\keys_define:nn { manuel/ellipsis }
 {
  comma   .code:n = \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_manuel_list_tl { { , } { \kern#1 } },
  unknown .code:n = \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_manuel_list_tl { { \l_keys_key_tl } { \kern#1 } },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manuel_lookup:
 {
  \peek_catcode:NF \c_space_token { \manuel_decide:n }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manuel_decide:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nVF { #1 } \g_manuel_list_tl { \skip_horizontal:n { .1em } }
  #1
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\SetEllipsisSpacing{
   . = .1em,
   ? = -.1em,
   ! = -.02em,
   : = -.02em,
   comma = .1em
}

\begin{document}
…! 
…: 
…? 
…, 
….
… a
…X
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since it's difficult to have a comma as a key, I've added the key `comma` for it.

Comment: This is nice, and better because of the `\SetEllipsisSpacing` command. By the way, I managed to do something similar but with `\tl_case:...` rather than `\str_case:...`. Is there a main difference/reason to use one versus the other one?

Comment: @Manuel `\tl_case:NnTF` requires a set of token list variables, `\str_case:nnTF` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Here I redefine `\ldots`  If the next character is one of the checked-for ones, the redefined macro inserts a custom amount of space before it.  REVISED to eliminate optional argument and hopefully get end-of-sentence spacing right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svldots\ldots
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ldots{\svldots%
  \@ifnextchar!{\kern10pt}{%
  \@ifnextchar:{\kern8pt}{%
  \@ifnextchar?{\kern6pt}{%
}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
NEW:

Here\ldots are\ldots! some\ldots: test\ldots? cases. Next\ldots

ORIGINAL:

Here\svldots are\svldots! some\svldots: test\svldots? cases. Next\svldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unless my eyes are deceiving me, the spaces after the exclamation and question marks are word spaces, not the usual end-of sentence spaces; i don't see `\frenchspacing` in the example, so i would expect the latter.

Comment: You should use `\futurelet` and `\if`, or spaces will be gobbled.

Comment: @egreg I see the problem barbara cites, but having extremely limited experience with `\futurelet`, I'm not exactly sure what you have in mind as the fix.

Comment: @Manuel Please see revision... optional argument gone.

Comment: @egreg I think this is fixed (without `\futurelet`), but I have trouble telling a normal space from an end-of-sentence space.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Thank you for your comment.  I think I have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

With a little bit of trial and error to find the `.09` which seems about right for this font at this size.

> [image: text ellipsis]

In `\Huge` size:

> [image: text ellipsis huge]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Just here to be an example, I use a different font

\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}
  {{\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont\char133}}

\newcommand\ellip [1]{\begingroup
                      \setbox0\hbox{\textellipsis}%
                      \setbox2\hbox{#1}%
                      \textellipsis\kern\dimexpr-.5\wd2+.09\wd0\relax
                                    #1\endgroup}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
a…! a…: a…?

a\textellipsis! a\textellipsis: a\textellipsis?

a\ellip! a\ellip: a\ellip?


\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it swallows every symbol. I would prefer some adjustable options, i.e., a certain kern for each character *I* define, and nothing for everything else.

Comment: It is not to be used systematically, only when the ellipsis is to be followed without spacing by some punctuation. You could do `\def\ellip#1{\csname ellip#1\endcsname}`, `\expandafter\def\csname ellip!\endcsname {…<whatever you want>!}`, etc..., naturally only if a few such characters are concerned, not dozens of them. But I don't see why one would like to do it for letters for example, or digits. Not much left then. (this method would not work if the characters are shorthands for babel, then one needs to replace `#1` by `\string#1` in the definition)

Comment: That's why this doesn't work (I think), because it doesn't differentiate between letters and other symbols. `…a` and `…!` would both change the spacing.

Comment: @Manuel but why would one ever type `…a` and not `… a`??

Comment: Yes, that's a rare case (which doesn't mean that it's okey if it doesn't work). But I would use `…»` or `…—` (an em-dash).

Answer (score 3):

You can use my `\ifeqcase` macro from the [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179333/new-command-with-cases)
and you can type:

```
\def\mydots{\dots\futurelet\next\mydotsA}
\def\mydotsA{\kern\ifeqcase\next {%
   ! {5em}
   ? {3em}
   , {1em}
  }{0pt}\relax
}

\mydots ?  \mydots !  \mydots ,
```

Of course, the spacing needs some correction.