# Comparing a macro against a constant string in base LaTeX/TeX

Tags: strings

Very often, I will have a macro that is one expansion away from a string that I would like to compare against a constant string. Now yes, obviously, I could simply define a macro that expands to the string I want to test against and use `\ifx` but that is very annoying to have define needless macros. I am also aware that one could use `stringstrings` or `xstring` to do this, but it seems unfortunate to have to import packages for something so conceptually simple. Here's an MWE illustrating what I'm referring to

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\teststring{xyz}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter{xyz}\textstring%
  TRUE%
\else%
  FALSE%
\fi%
\end{document}
```

This non-working solution is based off the [first answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179708/how-to-compare-against-a-constant-with-ifx?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it does not appear to work in the way the author claims.

Comment: There is *no* expandable string equality test in TeX (as implemented by Knuth). In derived engines (pdftex, XeTeX, LuaTeX, epTeX) one has `\(pdf)strcmp` (it's called with different names).

Comment: By the way, the code you claim is not working is about a rather different problem, where *one* character is tested to match a single character.

Comment: The `ifx` in your question is comparing `{` with `x` so will always be false (the `\expandafter` are expanding `x` which is not expandable so do nothing.

Comment: Okay I see. I had thought that grouping the `{xyz}` together would get it to be treated as a single token.

Comment: no `{xyz}` is 5 tokens

Comment: @KevinKeith: Try with [this code](https://pastebin.com/9ANVkN2Y). It does an elementary "string" comparison via `\ifx` using a macro `\teststring`.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [How do I perform an expandable string comparison?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306484/how-do-i-perform-an-expandable-string-comparison)