# Has LaTeX3 syntax possibly changed since this question was last answered

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3, latex3, xparse

I am adapting the LaTeX3 answer in this question:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61603

But I can't get the original MWE answer to compile using xelatex.  I have renamed the variables, but the error is the same whether I use it verbatim (not counting the `\str_case:nnn` fix) or slightly adapted.  So I am wondering if root syntax requirements have changed in the last couple of years since this question was answered?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\BuildTablePortion}{ O{Default} m }{%
    \my_BuildTablePortion:nn { #1 } { #2 }%
}

\cs_new:Npn \my_BuildTablePortion:nn #1 #2
{
    \str_case:nnn { #2 }{%
    {START} { Start data here}%
    {END} { End Data here}%
    % other possible strings
   }%
   {%
    I~don't~know~what~to~do~with~`#1'%
   }%
 }%

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\BuildTablePortion{START}

\BuildTablePortion{END}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no `str_case:nnn` and the solution of egreg has `\prog_case:nnn`

Comment: `\str_case:nnn` has been renamed. If the third argument was code to be inserted when no match is found then the new name is `\str_case:nnF`

Comment: @clemens: You were quicker, please write the answer

Comment: Thanks for noting: I fixed that old answer of mine. I think I searched for occurrences of `\str_case:nnn`, but that one escaped. You should have left a comment there, rather than asking a question.

Comment: @egreg: I find this question useful anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\str_case:nnn` has been renamed to `\str_case:nnF`. Actually *all* `\<module>_case:nnn` functions have been renamed to `\<module>_case:nnF` (also see [Function renaming: `\<thing>_case:nnn` to `\<thing>_case:nnF`](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/3021)).