# Setting a counter value based on a conditional statement?

Tags: conditionals, counters

I've been trying to google and this seems like a silly thing that should be obvious, but everywhere I look is answering how to use counter values inside a conditional statement, which I can do fine.

Basically I want to set a counter value, but inside the section where the value goes, put a if/then/else hierarchy. I know I can do it by reversing the order (putting an if/then/else hierarchy and in each result putting a new set-count command) but for both ease of reading and some programming structure reasons I'd rather have it the other way.

Basically I want to do something like the following;

```
\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{TestCounter}
{
\ifthenelse{5 > 6}{7}{2}
}
```

Is such a thing possible, or do I need to reorder it the other way?

Thanks!

For a more explicit MWE:

I want to use the following;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{TestCounter}{
\ifthenelse{5 > 6}{7}{2}}
\end{document}
```

Where (ideally) the above would result in assigning to the count "TestCounter" the value "2" (since 5 < 6).

In practice I would be using more complicated code, but it would all resolve to checking to see if one number is bigger than another, where one of those would be stored in a counter. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{Temp}
\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{Temp}{5}
\setcounter{TestCounter}{
     \ifthenelse{\arabic{Temp} > 2}{4}{7}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First you should provide us a MWE. See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61598/new-command-with-cases-conditionals-if-thens helps you.

Comment: Thought I had provided enough, but I have expanded it to have the pseudo-code I am after, with explanation of exactly how it should work. Let me know if you want more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\ifthenelse` is not expandable and can therefore not be used inside the arguments of `\setcounter`. However, the TeX primitive `\ifnum` is expandable:

```
\setcounter{TestCounter}{%
  \ifnum 5>6 % space ends number 6
    7%
  \else
    2%
  \fi
}
```

`\arabic` should not be used in numeric contexts, because it could contain formatting stuff like font settings. The value of a counter is accessable by `\value{countername}`:

```
\setcounter{TestCounter}{%
  \ifnum\value{Temp}>2 % space ends number 2
    4%
  \else
    7%
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: As a followup, my \arabic was entirely lazy and you bring up a good point.
Would using \theTemp be a good way to pull the value, or does that possibly have formatting attached as well?

Answer (score 2):

A simple wrapper may work here (at least for this simple example)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcommand{\ifelse}[3]{%
  \ifnum#1  
  #2%
  \else
  #3%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}


\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{TestCounter}{\ifelse{5 > 6}{7}{2}}


\theTestCounter


\setcounter{TestCounter}{\ifelse{6 > 5}{7}{2}}

\theTestCounter


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Temp}
\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{Temp}{5}

\begin{document}

\ifnum\theTemp>2
    \setcounter{TestCounter}{4}
\else
    \setcounter{TestCounter}{7}
\fi

\theTemp
\theTestCounter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Like I said, I know I can do it this way, and I may end up doing so if I haven't other choices, but it would be more tractable code if I could do it the other way, which is why I was asking if it was possible.

Comment: @Jason I do not understand what you mean by tractable. You can simply define a command with `\ifnum...\fi` and use that command anywhere in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a different set of “if-then-else” macros, for instance those provided by `etoolbox` or by `expl3`.

### `etoolbox`

Do `\usepackage{etoolbox}` in the preamble and use

```
\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{TestCounter}{\ifnumcomp{5}{>}{6}{7}{2}}
```

The relation symbol in between can be `<`, `=` or `>`.

### `expl3`

Do `\usepackage{expl3}` in the preamble, along with

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \intcompare \int_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

in order to have a “user level version” of the programming level function. Then

```
\newcounter{TestCounter}
\setcounter{TestCounter}{\intcompare{5 > 6}{7}{2}}
```

will do what you want.

With this version you can use (`A` and `B` represent integers, which can also be `\value{<counter>}`)

```
\intcompare{A < B}{true}{false}
\intcompare{A <= B}{true}{false}
\intcompare{A > B}{true}{false}
\intcompare{A >= B}{true}{false}
\intcompare{A = B}{true}{false}
\intcompare{A != B}{true}{false}
```

with obvious meanings; `=` can also be `==`.