# \newcommand with argument (cases) in macro within qrcode

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, xstring, qrcode

**This works**

`\newcommand` within `qrcode`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcommand{\aaa}{test1}
\newcommand{\aab}{test2}
\newcommand{\aac}{test3}

\begin{document}

\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\aaa}
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\aab}
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\aac}

\end{document}
```

**This works too**

`\newcommand` with argument within `qrcode`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{test1}}
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{test2}}
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{test3}}

\end{document}
```

**This doesn't work**

`\newcommand` with argument (which contains [cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61602/101831)) within `qrcode`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{test1}%
        {2}{test2}%
        {3}{test3}%
        % you can add more cases here as desired
    }[\PackageError{mylink}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}]%
}%

\begin{document}

\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{1}}
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{2}}
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{3}}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: One of the problems seems to be that when you call `\mylink` in the `\qrcode` the `\mylink` macro is not expanded and that causes an error. A simple solution to this is to force the expansion of `\mylink` using `\edef`: `\edef\mylink#1{\IfEqCase{#1}{<stuff>}[<error_stuff>]}`. But that leads to another error in the `\IfEqCase` macro, which I could not solve, so I'll leave to someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\IfEqCase` is not expandable and this causes the error. Use primitive `\ifcase` which is expandable:

```
\def\mylink#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or test1\or test2\or test3\else\errmessage{something wrong}\fi
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need an *expandable* case switch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \stringcase \str_case:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{%
  \stringcase{#1}{%
    {1}{test1}%
    {2}{test2}%
    {3}{test3}%
    % you can add more cases here as desired
  }{\PackageError{mylink}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}}%
} 

\begin{document}

\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{1}}\par\bigskip
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{2}}\par\bigskip
\qrcode[height=5cm]{www.domain.tld/\mylink{3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The log file has

```
<Reading QR code for "www.domain.tld/test1" at level 2-Q from aux file.>
<Reading QR code for "www.domain.tld/test2" at level 2-Q from aux file.>
<Reading QR code for "www.domain.tld/test3" at level 2-Q from aux file.>
```

One should note that the argument to `\mylink` is not limited to numbers, so

```
\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{%
  \stringcase{#1}{%
    {One}{test1}%
    {Two}{test2}%
    {Three}{test3}%
    % you can add more cases here as desired
  }{\PackageError{mylink}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}}%
}
```

with `\mylink{One}` and so on would work as well.