# Automatically add section label based on file name

Tags: labels, xstring, currfile

I am trying to automatically add section label based on the file name.
My structure is as such:

- main.tex
- 1.0.introduction.tex
- 1.1.0.foo.tex
- 1.1.1.bar.tex

I am using \currfilename from package **currfile** to get the filename {which removes the .tex} and **xstring** to remove everything before the last {.} up to three levels deep.

So my newcommand **clearname** is producing the expected result: from 1.0.introduction -> introduction.
The problem occurs when trying to add my command to the label.

While *\label{\currfilename}* works and the label gets created, when doing \label{\clearname{\currfilename}} I get 6 different compilation errors which I am too of a novice to wrap my head around.

**MWE:**

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\newcommand{\clearname}[1]{%
    \StrCount{#1}{.}[\tmp]
    \IfEqCase{\tmp}{%
        {1}{\StrBehind{#1}{.}}%
        {2}{\StrBehind{#1}{.}[\tmp2]\StrBehind{\tmp2}{.}}%
        {3}{\StrBehind{#1}{.}[\tmp2]\StrBehind{\tmp2}{.}[\tmp3]\StrBehind{\tmp3}{.}}
    }
  }
\begin{document}
\input{1.0.introduction}
\end{document}
```

**1.0.introduction.tex**

```
\section{Introduction}
\currfilename
\label{\currfilename}

\clearname{\currfilename}

% \label{\clearname{\currfilename}}

As clearly seen in \ref{1.0.introduction}
```

So to summarize I need the label created to be `introduction` and not `1.0.introduction`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TexSE :) // Sorry, may be I miss your point. Don't you specify the section to be "Introduction" manually? Didn't you want s.th. like \label{\clearname ...} ?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! There's hundreds of files representing sections, subsections etc which already have the correct label I would like to use. The section names on the other hand are not as good a match for labels as they can be a couple words. I'd rather not spend the time to manually assign labels whose names I'd like to use are already laying around anyway.

Comment: So yes, I would like to use \label{\clearname{\currfilename}} which is not working. I suspect it's about xstring not allowing expansion of the command inside \label but it supersedes my latex skills to "define \clearname globally". I have tried Mr. Carlisle's suggestion from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61598/new-command-with-cases-conditionals-if-thens) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... After spending a few hours on the very detailed and intricate [xstring](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/xstring/xstring-en.pdf) documentation...
In order to get the expansion of xstring macros you have to pass an argument to the output such as: **[\myresult]**.

I also realized what I need can easily be achieved by **\StrGobbleLeft**:

So to elaborate the below code works as expected:

```
\newcommand{\clearname}[1]{%
    \StrCount{#1}{.}[\tmp]
    \IfEqCase{\tmp}{%
    {1}{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{2}[\myresult]}%
    {2}{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{4}[\myresult]}%
    {3}{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{6}[\myresult]}
    }
  }
```

...and produces the correct result by calling **\label{\myresult}** although you still need to run **\clearname{\currfilename}** before.

Comment: Congratulations :)

Comment: Thanks, I was already using the solution witihn the \clearname declaration anyway with the \tmp, I just hadn't understood it was needed for the output as well. Answering my first question on SE on my own kind of defeats the purpose but hey... Oh well..

Comment: I agree, xstring's documentation is challenging. A few suggestions to find faster what you need. // 0) Posting a question here is a valid approach ;-) // 1) Sometimes in the column to the right "Latest" or "Related" can give a clue. // 2) Upper left, try a Tag-search. I sometimes use it to get a quick overview about a package, its features and troubles. // 3) Try a google search like `xstring extract` and similar. // Purpose is getting clues, not detailed reading. // Anyway ... you made it :)

Comment: Thanks for your input once again. I had already done all the steps you mention and had spent around 5 hours on reading similar SE questions before deciding to post and finally tackle the daunting manual. Maybe just writing it down as a question for others to understand cleared things up for me.